# Make / work in %slug%

Tags: javascript

I use `schnack` commenting sytem: [schnack-commenting-system](https://github.com/schn4ck/schnack)

I successfully made `slack` webhook.

In files:

slack.js:
`const post_url = config.get('page_url').replace('%SLUG%', event.slug)+'#comment-'+event.id;`

page_url:
`"page_url": "https://example.com/%SLUG%",`

In blogpost:

```html
<h1 id="try-schnack">
<a class="anchor" href="#try-schnack">
 Try schnack</a>
 </h1>
<div class="comments-go-here"></div>
<% var title = post.title %>
<% var slug = post.slug %>
<% var sluglink = [title,slug].join('+++++') %>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://schnack.example.com/embed.js" 
 data-schnack-slug="<%= sluglink %>"
    data-schnack-target=".comments-go-here">
</script>
```

This all works.
But I need output following: `title/slug` and NOT `title+++++slug`

If I do `.join('/')` then schnack does not work at all, it crashes. 
I need the slash `/` as separator between `title` and `slug`, so my result is this: `title/slug`.

How to make that?

Comment: Have you tried escaping the forward slash character in your join function? `.join('\/')`

Comment: @wlh - just tried, did not work.